# Call Controller Function from Laravel Routes.php

Tags: php, post, controller, laravel

I have a function in my `Orders_Controller` in Laravel called getOrders($user). It calls a raw DB query and builds a JSON array to return.

I cannot figure out how to call this function from within my routes file.

Basically I receive a POST in the routes, insert the new Order, then I want to call getOrders(user) from this Routes function to get all the existing Orders for the given user.

Can someone help me figure out how to call this function from within Routes.php?

Routes.php

```
//Handle a new order POST
Route::post('order', array('do' => function() {
    ...
    ... //HANDLE POST DATA AND INSERT NEW ORDER
    ...

    //GET ALL ORDERS FOR THIS USER FROM ORDER CONTROLLER
    $userOrders = Order_Controller::myOrders($thisUser);
}
```

order.php (in Controllers folder)

```
class Order_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public function myOrders($user){
        return DB::query("SELECT ...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested from larauser you could move your myOrders() method to a model and call it statically. Here's an example

```
class Order extends Eloquent {

    public static function myOrders($user)
    {
         // DB call here
    }
}
```

Then in your route you could do

```
Route::post('order/(:num)', function($user)
{
    $userOrders = Order::myOrders($user);

    // Do stuff here
});
```

I'm guessing you're passing the user ID that's the reason i'm using (:num) in the route.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So should I really be handling the POST data in the controller, then calling this function from within the Controller? I'm trying to understand the best way to implement Laravel on an existing site, but I'm not sure how the Routes/Controller/Model should work together.

Comment: @jamis0n You could also do that (my preference). You dont event need to have a route if you have registered your controller and your routing is simple as in your case. To register your controllers you need to call `Route::controller(array('order', 'anothercontroller'));` in your routes files

Comment: Gotcha... So if I removed the POST route from Routes.php, then a POST to orders will be caught in the orders controller if implemented by the Laravel example I just added to your answer?

Comment: Awesome thanks... I'll explore both! Can you also help me understand exactly what making the function static does in this case? Is it required because I'm calling it as a function of the class and not from an instance of an object?

Comment: @afarazit why is `myOrders()` a static function?

Comment: @Justin If you check his example you'll see he wanted static `$userOrders = Order_Controller::myOrders($thisUser);` so I followed his example. Doesn't have to be static tho.

Answer (score 7):

Easier way is call controller as class

```
Route::post( 'post', function() use ($user) {
  return (new OrderController)->myOrders($user);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another way that I have used, maybe incorrectly, but it might work for you.

```
$userOrders = Controller::call('order@myOrders', array($thisUser))->content
```

For more information and how to use it check out the documentation for the [Controller class](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Laravel.Routing.Controller.html#117).

Comment: This doesn't work for me; I've had better luck with: `URL::action('FooController@method');` or the corresponding helper:
`action('FooController@method');`
http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: Yeah this reply was based on Laravel 3 and so it's probably changed. Haven't checked for a while.

Comment: Just had a quick look and there is now `Controller::callAction()` in Laravel 4 which looks like it would do the same thing - check it out and let me know if it works. Goto [http://laravel.com/api/4.1/](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/) and search for 'callAction'

Comment: tx for the followup: I did try that, but I get: `ErrorException
Non-static method Illuminate\Routing\Controller::callAction() should not be called statically`.  This thread http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=39972 mentions it; Taylor added something back in (missingMethod? I've lost the github issue now), but I didn't grok it :/

Answer (score 3):

the myOrders function should probably go in your orders model since its working with data access.  Then, to call it you'd do Orders::myOrders($user).

Answer (score 1):

Routes.php

```
//Handle a new order POST
Route::post('orders/(:num)', function($user) {
    ...
    ... //HANDLE POST DATA AND INSERT NEW ORDER
    ...
});

Route::get('orders', function($user) {
   //GET ALL ORDERS FOR THIS USER FROM ORDER MODEL
   $userOrders = Order::myOrders($user)->get();
});
```

application/models/Order.php

```
class Order extends Eloquent
{
    public static function myOrders($user_id)
    {
        return Order::where_user_id($user_id);
    }
}
```